# Redirections with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect, python-requests

I have a URL that looks like `http://www.example.com/link?url=http://www.google.com`. And the URL redirects to `http://www.google.com` when opened in the browser. But when I check the status code of the URL, it shows 200 instead of 3xx. Even if I check with `print(url.history)` it shows `[]`. Please explain!

I checked the response of the request it was like :

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
window.location=url;
</script>
<!-- Form pop up box -->
    <div id="popUpPageConatiner" style="display:none;" ></div>
<!-- close form pop up box -->
```

Comment: How is this a redirect? Redirect happens from the server. Your code shows that the original page loads on client, followed by a script that changes the url on the window - which is not redirect.

Comment: You can get `3xx` only if server sends response with redirection. If page uses JavaScript to redirect then it is treated as normal click on link. But `requests` can't run JavaScript so you can get only first page, not redirection, and you get empty history.